# Can tutoring be counted as `Experience dealing with the general public, one-on-one`?

Tags: communication, applications, work-experience, customer-service

I'm applying for a job in a English-speaking country. In the section `Customer service and communication skills` of the questionnaire, I am asked to state my `Experience dealing with the general public, one-on-one`.

My only work experience was tutoring children and talking to their parents, sometimes in a one-on-one manner. The organisation I worked with was a NGO providing free / low-fee tutorial classes to the general public. Can this be counted as `Experience dealing with the general public, one-on-one`? If not, how should I answer this question?

My understanding is that I may still get that job if I'm not the perfect candidate, but I'll have to write something sensible to maximise my chance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it might not be the type of experience that they were expecting, this is exactly customer relations!

> Experience dealing with the general public, one-on-one

> Customer service and communication skills

This type of experience is different to the experience with tutoring, the student-tutor relationship will likely be of less value in this role, though it is still important to include on your CV.

The important aspect is your experience communicating with the *parents*, they are the customers in the tutor engagement, so focus on your ability to communicate and mediate or negotiate with the parents. In fact parents of children being tutored *(in my experience)* often provide the most character building interactions you might face, their interest is *always* deeply personal and so this can lead to some interesting exchanges.

I would suggest something along these lines:

> I have been working with XXXX for XXXX years providing free / low-fee tutorial classes to the children. This was an offering to the general public so there was a mix of new customers I had not been introduced to an important aspect of the role is to develop these customers into long term clients. Apart from the initial interactions there was frequent 1 on 1 interactions with the parents where we would discuss expectations, progress and strategies to continue study outside of our session times. I feel my experience will help me to establish good working relationships with customers, especially when they have issues that they are passionate about and expecting answers or solutions. I respect the fact that everyone has their own personal priorities and points of view and my experience has helped me develop strategies to diffuse volatile situations if they occur. I am by nature a problem solver and enjoy the challenge of identifying the real issues and presenting practical solutions to clients. I have been able to build a good rapport with all of my customers to date.

Insert a mention of a reference if you can, one of your "customers", or describe or be ready to describe an actual scenario where you were forced to *think on your toes* and deal with a situation that could easily have escalated out of hand.

See how we've easily turned a *might not be appropriate* into the perfect candidate for the role ;)